# How can I search my ENTIRE git repo's commit history for a string change?

Tags: regex, git, version-control, git-log

I have a website/repo.

Part of my website says:

"Powered by https://myotherwebsite.com/'"

at some point, some troll I had working on the website switched it to say:

"Powered by https://theirwebsite.com"

How can I search the entire repo history to the commit where this change was made.

There have been A LOT of commits/branches over the years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can ignore dead branches and assume that all relevant code is reachable from your most recent master version, I'd recommend using the `-S` option of git log :

```
git log -S "theirwebsite"
```

Take a look at the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Sltstringgt), and maybe consider using [regexp](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Gltregexgt) search if your actual need is or becomes more complex than what you described here.

---

**Even better** : with `--all` you can search your entire repo (thanks to [j6t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868543/j6t) for the trick!)

```
git log --all -S "theirwebsite"
```

(and, as noted by vfalcao, consider using the `--name-only` option here to list files where this change happened.)

Comment: The restriction to ignore dead branches is not necessary. Just add `--all` to the suggested `git log` command to search all branches.

Comment: consider using  `git log --all --name-only -S "theirwebsite"`, which is going to list the files changed in each commit as well. It can help you to narrow down the exact changing point.

Comment: @vfalcao Thanks, I had failed to notice your comment at the time!