# How to `git grep` through a range of commits, all commits from the current commit back to the parent commit, or through all commits in entire repo

Tags: git, git-grep

I'd like to be able to use `git grep` to do a regular expression search through:

1. the current commit
2. a given commit
3. a list of commits
4. a range of commits
5. a given commit all the way back to the parent commit
6. *all* commits (and branches) in the entire repo

**To do 1**, you just do this:

```bash
git grep -n "some regex search string"
```

**To do 2**, you do this:

```bash
git grep -n "some regex search string" commit_hash_or_branch_name
```

**To do 3**, you just list all the commits like this:

```bash
git grep -n "some regex search string" commit1 commit2 commit3 commit4
```

But, how do we do 4, 5, or 6?

I tried this for 4, for instance, but it does *not* work:

```bash
git grep -n "some regex search string" beginning_commit~..end_commit
```

I thought this pattern *might* work since it works for `git cherry-pick`s, [as I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69472178/4561887), but, it doesn't work for `git grep`.

### See also

1. Related, but *not* the same thing, since it looks for a string *change*, not a string *existence*: [How can I search my ENTIRE git repo's commit history for a string change?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54567567/4561887)
2. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions (thanks, [@JohnKugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930303/how-to-git-grep-through-a-range-of-commits-all-commits-from-the-current-commi#comment130538532_73930303))

Comment: See [gitrevisions - Specifying revisions and ranges for Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Update: see my new answer here instead: [All about searching (via `grep` or similar) in your git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77917015/4561887)

---

### How to `git grep` through whichever branches or commits you choose

Alright, with much effort, I figured it out. Here is how to do 4, 5, and 6:

> 4. a range of commits
> 5. a given commit all the way back to the parent commit
> 6. *all* commits (and branches) in the entire repo

### 4. `git grep` a range of commits

To search for `"search string"` within a range of commits, from `commit1`, inclusive, to `commit2`, inclusive, do this:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" commit1~..commit2)"; \
    git grep -n "search string" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

Here is an example that searches for `"\bhey\b"` (`\b` means "word boundary" in regular expressions) which you can run in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" f714d2fb18b00f0f423de98b6a7a418e42054cfe~..f396a4ae24153b35215335a1d6bf35ac843ad122)"; \
    git grep -n "\bhey\b" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

#### Explanation

`IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a myarray <<< "$multiline_string"` converts a multiline string into a bash array named `myarray`. See my answer here: [How to read a multi-line string into a regular bash "indexed" array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575442/4561887).

To get a range of commits, you can use this trick:

```bash
git log --pretty=format:%H fist_commit~..last_commit
```

Source where I got the necessary hints to learn the `git log --pretty=format:%H` part: [Get the short Git version hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694454/4561887).

Example usage and output, when in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo. Here you can see the first commit I specify at the very bottom of the output, and the last commit at the very top:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ git log --pretty=format:%H f714d2fb18b00f0f423de98b6a7a418e42054cfe~..f396a4ae24153b35215335a1d6bf35ac843ad122
f396a4ae24153b35215335a1d6bf35ac843ad122
d00f645cc56b5f4bf8b3c7b23c6ff62ca71734d7
0a795f56c2dd343e50d8c4f73f1347759ece9a08
f714d2fb18b00f0f423de98b6a7a418e42054cfe
```

### 5. `git grep` a given commit all the way back to the parent commit

This command is a subset of the command above, and is even simpler. To search for `"search string"` from `commit`, inclusive, all the way back to the first (most-parent) commit, do this:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" commit)"; \
    git grep -n "search string" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

Example from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" f396a4ae24153b35215335a1d6bf35ac843ad122)"; \
    git grep -n "\bhey\b" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

### 6. `git grep` a whole repository: ie: *all* commits (and branches) in the entire repo

Same as just above, except use `--all` in place of the branch name or commit hash:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" --all)"; \
    git grep -n "search string" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

Example from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" --all)"; \
    git grep -n "\bhey\b" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

### Alternative solutions and hints

#### A. To search for *changes* of a search pattern or word, you can do this:

1. Search up from the current commit:

   ```bash
   git log -S "some string"
   ```
2. Search all branches:

   ```bash
   git log --all -S "some string"
   ```

See: [How can I search my ENTIRE git repo's commit history for a string change?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54567708/4561887).

#### B. To search through just the *changes* introduced by each commit, use `git log -p` and search interactively through the *less* viewer:

You can also search for a match in your history like this: `git log -p`, then press the <kbd>/</kbd> key, type your regular expression search string, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>n</kbd> for "next match" or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> for "previous match". The `-p` in `git log` shows the changes in "patch" format for each commit. And, since the output of `git log` is viewed in the `less` viewer, you can use it to search the contents interactively.

#### C. Use `git log --grep <regex> <branches>`

...as described here: [Search a whole Git repository](https://superuser.com/a/1008441/425838).

Answer (score 2):

fwiw, a perhaps shorter way to feed "a range of commits" to `git grep` :

For 4. :

```
git grep -n -e pattern "$(git rev-list a..b)" --
```

For 5. :

```
git grep -n -e pattern "$(git rev-list $parent..HEAD)" "$parent" --
```

For 6. :

```
git grep -n -e pattern "$(git rev-list --all)" --
```

---

regarding your alternative solutions and hints :

`A.` and `B.` are correct,
regarding `C.` : beware of `git log --grep pattern` : it will search for the pattern in *the commit messages*, as opposed to `git grep` which searches in *the content of the files in the commit*.

To add to `B.` : in `git log`, the `-p` option combines with `-G pattern` or `-S pattern` : only the files which contribute to the `-G` or `-S` filtering will be listed (makes for a shorter diff). The "search in file" you suggest is still useful to spot that pattern within the diffs.

Comment: I finally figured out after all these years how to do this with `xargs` to make it multi-process and faster!: [All about searching (via `grep` or similar) in your git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77917015/4561887)

Comment: @GabrielStaples : for that matter you may also look into [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html), which is a pretty thorough swiss army toolbox for running tasks in parallel